# Dictionary<string, list<string>> iteration ASP.NET2.0

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, I used to get back to value using

```
List<string> keyDicoList = DictErrorCorrectionBeforeJS.Keys.ToList();
List<string> listValue = DictErrorCorrectionBeforeJS.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

But it seems on production ae using ASP.NET 2.0 when we Dev in 4.0...
So I try to recover them with another way.I find for the Key :

```
foreach (string key in DictErrorCorrection.Keys)
{
    keyDicoList.Add(key);
}
```

But i have trouble getting the value. As it is not a simple value but a List inside the Dictionnary. I can't do a foreach on it and it seems as it is an enumerator that I can't just go for a for loop, with just adding the Dico.Values[x] to my listValue

How should I proceed to get all the dictionary.value inside my listValue ?

Comment: 1. Line up your dev environment with your production environment....having two different environments is for all practical purposes coding blindly.

Comment: @user2366842 as an external ressource it seems my opinion on this point haven't been taken (neither for the fact that we are in IE5)

Comment: Tell them that you don't have a sufficient setup to do your job in that case, because you honestly don't, if that's the case.  EDIT: and you can't scale back your own dev environment???

Comment: 2005 called, they want their framework back.

Comment: @user2366842 it's been 5 month that I tell them that our PROD and PREPROD server are not even on the same version... and as the 2.0 is the lowest I need it to work on this version.

Comment: Old framework is fine, as long as its consistent across the board.

Comment: If you donwvote explain why maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over them using a `foreach`. The dictionary enumerator yields a `KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in dictionary)
{
    string key = kvp.Key;
    List<string> list = kvp.Value;

    foreach (string listItem in list)
    {
        // .. use the item, or skip the foreach and use the list at once
    }
}
```

Comment: the enumerator will automaticaly loop inside my value list ?

Comment: Inside the dictionary, you can loop over the list again if you want to.

Comment: So i can just complete my 2 list Key and value with this technique and i will retrieve one Key + all his value each time (in two separated list) ?

Comment: It retrieves it indeed. What you do with it is to you.

Comment: I have modified your work for it to match what I need but it gave me some solid base for what I use, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you enumerate the KVP set of the dictionary:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in dict)
{
    values.AddRange(kvp.Value); // kvp.Value is List<string>
}
```